# C# - Application gets suspended on startup after boot

Tags: c#, windows, boot, regedit

I have an option in my application to boot on startup. This used to work fine, but now it doesn't work anymore like it should. When I check the Task Manager right after booting up the system, I can see that the application boots, gets suspended and killed by Windows.

I use the following piece of code to set the Registery key:

```
private void checkBox_startOnBoot_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //Update settings, set value of registery key
{
    if (checkBox_startOnBoot.Checked)
    {
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
        {
            key.SetValue(Application.ProductName, Application.ExecutablePath);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
        {
            key.SetValue(Application.ProductName, false);
        }
    }

    Settings.Default.Start_On_Boot = checkBox_startOnBoot.Checked;
    Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

I do not see anything in the Main() function that can cause the malfunction:

```
static void Main()
{
    if (Settings.Default.Restarting)
    {
        Settings.Default.Restarted = true;
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }
    using (oneInstanceMutex = new Mutex(false, "Global\\" + appGuid))
    {
        if (!oneInstanceMutex.WaitOne(0, false)) // If app already running, but is not restarting // && restartMutex.WaitOne(0, false)
        {
            if (!Settings.Default.Restarting)
            {
                AlreadyRunning();
                return;
            }
        }


        hpt = new HookProcThread();
        hpt.Run();

        SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += OnPowerChange;

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        mw = new MainWindow();
        if (Settings.Default.Restarted)
        {
            mw.WindowState = (FormWindowState)Settings.Default.RestartingWindowMode;
        }
        Settings.Default.Restarting = false;
        Settings.Default.Save();
        Application.Run(mw);
    }
}
```

So if anyone has an idea how I can prevent the application to get suspended and killed on boot, that would be great!

Comment: You program is running exactly like a virus would run, especially being as it alters the registry! I'd imagine windows defender or an anti virus program is suspending it. Really if you want this functionality you should have this installed as a windows service.

Comment: @Liam, weird never had this before. Is it possible that if I copy the .exe file to the Startup folder that it might fix it? What else can I do to prevent it looking like a virus. Also, the application is certified by Digicert so why would Windows block it with a certificate?

Comment: In all likelihood, the "suspended and gets killed" is just a symptom of Windows taking a crash dump after your application dies with an unhandled exception. Check the event viewer.

Comment: Anything in the event logs?

Comment: @JeroenMoster Great call! Didn't look there but turns out there is file which cannot be found. Will try to fix that and see if that also fixes the whole boot problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, there was a file that couldn't be found. [@JeroenMostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) and [huysentruitw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1300910/huysentruitw) both pointed me in the right direction to look in the event viewer, which showed me the error.